# C++, ternary operator and cout

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

this code doesn't work

```
int main(){
cout << 5 ? (5 ? 0 : 2) : 5;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

this code works

```
int main(){
cout << (5 ? (5 ? 0 : 2) : 5);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

can't understand why?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of that ternary operator? It only contains literal integers, so wouldn't it make much more sense to just hardcode the result?

Comment: In that case, could you replace it with a better example?

Comment: What do you even mean by "works" and "works not"? What happens and what did you expect?

Comment: @user3092693 `this code does not work`  It works fine.  It's no different than `5 + 2 * 8` being equal to `21`, and `(5 + 2) * 8` equal to `56` -- both work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cout << 5 ? (5 ? 0 : 2) : 5;
```

is parsed as

```
(cout << 5) ? (5 ? 0 : 2) : 5;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is due to operator precedence rules.

`<<` has higher precedence than `?`, so your first expression is parsed as:

```
(cout << 5) ? (5 ? 0 : 2) : 5;
```

Brackets are necessary in this case to get the parse you want.